# Error when library ggplot2 and survminer

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I have the following error when I'm using the `ggplot2` and `survminer` packages.

I really have no idea why the warning appeared.

```
> install.packages(c("survival", "survminer", "ggplot2"))
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/xu081/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL         'https://mirrors.tongji.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/survival_2.42-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4584781 bytes (4.4 MB)
downloaded 4.4 MB

trying URL     'https://mirrors.tongji.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/survminer_0.4.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2849057 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

trying URL     'https://mirrors.tongji.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/ggplot2_2.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2784778 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

package ‘survival’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘survival’
package ‘survminer’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\xu081\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuOtZaF\downloaded_packages
> library(survival)
> library(ggplot2)
Error in UseMethod("conditionCall") : 
  no applicable method for 'conditionCall' applied to an object of class         "character"
> library(survminer)
载入需要的程辑包：ggplot2
Error in UseMethod("conditionCall") : 
  no applicable method for 'conditionCall' applied to an object of class     "character"

> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xu081/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL'https://mirrors.tongji.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/devtools_1.13.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 443954 bytes (433 KB)
downloaded 433 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\xu081\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpa62LXv\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
> devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
Downloading GitHub repo tidyverse/ggplot2@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/tidyverse/ggplot2/zipball/master
Installing ggplot2
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \

"C:/Users/xu081/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpa62LXv/devtools1dac50bf8ef/tidyverse-ggplot2-4463da6"  \
  --library="C:/Users/xu081/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in UseMethod("conditionCall") : 
  "conditionCall"没有适用于"character"目标对象的方法
* removing 'C:/Users/xu081/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/xu081/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in UseMethod("conditionMessage") : 
  no applicable method for 'conditionMessage' applied to an object of class 
"character"
```

I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with that specific version of `ggplot` you've installed since it doesn't download from CRAN but from a mirror source I'm not familiar with. Can you try to install `ggplot` from Github instead, do `install.packages("devtools")` then `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")` see if that works for you

Comment: I already try it but still turned out the same error and i edited my code in the question. Besides, i tried to download the package from another CRAN but it's not working either.

Comment: I just found my R and Rstudio were not the latest version and i updated them. And the error is fixed. Really appreciate for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks for posting the update (and nope no thanks required I wasn’t being helpful at all)